How to fix thread issue with Dataflow job from GAE standard environment?
I want to use Dataflow, from a Google App Engine application (in a Standard environment), in java 21.
But I get the following error :
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error while staging packages
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.util.PackageUtil.stageClasspathElements(PackageUtil.java:372)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.util.PackageUtil.stageClasspathElements(PackageUtil.java:238)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.util.GcsStager.stageFiles(GcsStager.java:53)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.DataflowRunner.stageArtifacts(DataflowRunner.java:1068)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.DataflowRunner.run(DataflowRunner.java:1217)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.DataflowRunner.run(DataflowRunner.java:203)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.run(Pipeline.java:325)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.run(Pipeline.java:310)
   ...
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.lambda$static$0(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:52)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:146)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:189)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$ResponseOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:176)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:93)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:478)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:400)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:81)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:274)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:248)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:244)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:292)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:274)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:244)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:266)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:253)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:696)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:397)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:349)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:358)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:312)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:205)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.ee10.servlet.ServletHolder$NotAsync.service(ServletHolder.java:1379)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.ee10.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:736)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.ee10.servlet.ServletHandler$ChainEnd.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1614)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.ee10.JdbcMySqlConnectionCleanupFilter.doFilter(JdbcMySqlConnectionCleanupFilter.java:78)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.ee10.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:205)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.ee10.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1586)
    at  ... MyFilter
    at org.eclipse.jetty.ee10.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:205)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.ee10.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1586)
    at  ... MyFilter2
    at org.eclipse.jetty.ee10.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:205)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.ee10.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1586)
    at  ... MyFilter3
    at org.eclipse.jetty.ee10.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:205)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.ee10.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1586)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.ee10.ParseBlobUploadFilter.doFilter(ParseBlobUploadFilter.java:120)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.ee10.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:208)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.ee10.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1586)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.ee10.servlet.ServletHandler$MappedServlet.handle(ServletHandler.java:1547)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.ee10.servlet.ServletChannel.dispatch(ServletChannel.java:824)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.ee10.servlet.ServletChannel.handle(ServletChannel.java:436)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.ee10.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:464)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:575)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.ee10.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:703)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:1060)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.ee10.AppEngineWebAppContext.handle(AppEngineWebAppContext.java:301)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HotSwapHandler.handle(HotSwapHandler.java:90)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.AppVersionHandler.handle(AppVersionHandler.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Handler$Wrapper.handle(Handler.java:740)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.CoreSizeLimitHandler.handle(CoreSizeLimitHandler.java:75)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:181)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.internal.HttpChannelState$HandlerInvoker.run(HttpChannelState.java:661)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.delegate.internal.DelegateConnection.lambda$handle$0(DelegateConnection.java:146)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.JettyServletEngineAdapter$2.run(JettyServletEngineAdapter.java:128)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.delegate.internal.DelegateConnection.handle(DelegateConnection.java:142)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.delegate.DelegateConnector.service(DelegateConnector.java:49)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.JettyServletEngineAdapter.serviceRequest(JettyServletEngineAdapter.java:255)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.RequestRunner.dispatchServletRequest(RequestRunner.java:349)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.RequestRunner.dispatchRequest(RequestRunner.java:234)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.RequestRunner.run(RequestRunner.java:200)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ThreadGroupPool$PoolEntry.run(ThreadGroupPool.java:273)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583)
caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Operation not allowed in a thread that is neither the original request thread nor a thread created by ThreadManager
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ApiProxyImpl$CurrentRequestThreadFactory.newThread(ApiProxyImpl.java:1368)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.<init>(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:637)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.addWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:928)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.execute(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1364)
    at org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v32_1_2_jre.com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors$ListeningDecorator.execute(MoreExecutors.java:640)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.asyncRunStage(CompletableFuture.java:1818)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.runAsync(CompletableFuture.java:2033)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.util.MoreFutures.supplyAsync(MoreFutures.java:105)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.util.PackageUtil.stagePackage(PackageUtil.java:141)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.util.PackageUtil.lambda$stageClasspathElements$2(PackageUtil.java:324)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniCompose.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:1150)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$Completion.run(CompletableFuture.java:482)
    ... 1 common frames elided

Could someone help me ? How can I start a Dataflow job in a way compliant to the non-thread GAE policy ?
Here an extract of my pom :
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.beam</groupId>
        <artifactId>beam-sdks-java-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.59.0</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.beam</groupId>
        <artifactId>beam-runners-google-cloud-dataflow-java</artifactId>
        <version>2.59.0</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.beam</groupId>
        <artifactId>beam-sdks-java-io-google-cloud-platform</artifactId>
        <version>2.59.0</version>
      </dependency>

Here my code for starting the job. It's run in an async task (on a queue). The goal is to update all Entities of one Kind on the Datastore :

    DataflowPipelineOptions dataflowOptions = PipelineOptionsFactory.as(DataflowPipelineOptions.class);
    dataflowOptions.setRunner(DataflowRunner.class);
    dataflowOptions.setProject("myproject");
    dataflowOptions.setRegion("europe-west1");
    String dataflowBucket = "mybucket";
    dataflowOptions.setTempLocation("gs://" + dataflowBucket + "/tmp");
    dataflowOptions.setStagingLocation("gs://" + dataflowBucket + "/staging");

    Pipeline pipeline = Pipeline.create(dataflowOptions);

    // Step 2: Read from Google Cloud Datastore
    log.info("step 2 : Read from Google Cloud Datastore");
    String projectId = AppEngine.ID;
    String entityKind = "MyEntity";
    PCollection<Entity> entities = pipeline.apply(
        "ReadFromDatastore",
        DatastoreIO.v1().read().withProjectId(projectId)
            .withLiteralGqlQuery("SELECT * FROM " + entityKind)
    );

    // Step 3: Modify entities
    log.info("step 3 : modify entities");
    PCollection<Entity> modifiedEntities = entities.apply(
        "ModifyEntities",
        ParDo.of(new DoFn<Entity, Entity>() {
          @ProcessElement
          public void processElement(ProcessContext c) {
            Entity entity = c.element();
            // Create a mutable version of the entity
            Entity.Builder modifiedEntityBuilder = Entity.newBuilder(entity);

            // Modify some properties
            String fieldName = "name";
            String defaultValue = "defaultName";
            Value oldValue = entity.getPropertiesOrDefault(fieldName, makeValue(defaultValue).build());
            log.info("step 3 : oldValue = " + oldValue.getStringValue());
            String newValue = oldValue.getStringValue() + "_modified";
            modifiedEntityBuilder.putProperties(fieldName, makeValue(newValue).build());

            // Emit the modified entity
            c.output(modifiedEntityBuilder.build());
          }
        })
    );

    // Step 4: Write modified entities back to Datastore
    log.info("step 4 : Write modified entities back to Datastore");

    modifiedEntities.apply(
        "WriteToDatastore",
        DatastoreIO.v1().write().withProjectId(projectId)
    );

    // Step 5: Run the pipeline
    log.info("step 5 : Run the pipeline - begin");
    pipeline.run().waitUntilFinish();
    log.info("step 5 : Run the pipeline - end");

I've found this post where someone has the same issue, but there is no answer.
